# store selected value of multiple list box items in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a listbox control data bound to a data source and I want to be able to get the value of each selected item so that I can use that information to form an insert query for another table. In other words be able to select a few items out of the returned list and get the selected value of each. I tried using a for each statement but came up with some strange numbers.

Comment: Could you add the code which you are currently using and a detailed explanation of the results you are getting and the results you expect.

Comment: I only know how to get one selected value: listbox1.selectedvalue. My list box is hooked up to a sqldatasource and I need to get the selected value(not text, but value) of each item so that I can create a stored procedure that inserts the selected values into another table. For instance, my table returns sub models for every vehicle make/model. I'm building an app that allows me to select the year/make/model, but then select multiple items from a long list of sub models and assign them to each model for each make in the particular year I selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string msg = "";

    foreach (ListItem li in ListBox_SubModel.Items)
    {
        if (li.Selected == true)
        {
            msg += "<br />" + li.Value + " is selected";
        }
    }
    Label_SubModel.Text = msg;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example with a list box allowing multiple items to be selected and a button which retrieves the selected items:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" %>
<script type="text/C#" runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            list.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => new { Id = x, Text = "item " + x });
            list.DataValueField = "Id";
            list.DataTextField = "Text";
            list.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void BtnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListItem[] selectedItems = list.Items
            .Cast<ListItem>()
            .Where(item => item.Selected)
            .ToArray();
        // TODO: use the selected items here
    }
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListBox ID="list" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="BtnOK" runat="server" OnClick="BtnOK_Click" Text="OK" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```